# should I run keras pad_sequence on numpy array

Tags: numpy, keras

I'm working with audio data. I am loading audio using the [soundfile](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/) package which returns a `numpy.ndarray`.

I need to pad the samples to a fixed length so my Neural Network can process it. I am aware of the [pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences) preprocessing step but it accepts a list of lists, not `ndarray`.

I can make the function run by doing

```
keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences([sample.tolist() for sample in dataset])
```

but this converts the numpy arrays into lists and back. Is there are more efficient way to zeropad my dataset?

```
import os                                                                      
import keras                                                                   
import soundfile as sf                                                         

train_dir = '../input/songs/songs'                                             
paths = [os.path.join(train_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(train_dir)]            
dataset = []                                                                   
for p in paths:                                                          
    audio, _ = sf.read(p)                                                      
    dataset.append(audio)                                                      

dataset = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences([p.tolist() for p in dataset])
dataset.shape
```

benchmark https://www.kaggle.com/morenoh149/pad-sequences-soundfile

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the goal of `pad_sequences` is to produce a 2D Numpy array of the `(num_samples, num_timesteps)` shape, where `num_timesteps` is either the maxlen argument if provided, or the length of the longest sequence otherwise.

So why do you need to pad an array which is already 2D array (padded)?

Comment: I need to pad the array's inside my list (`dataset` is a list of numpy arrays). It is not already 2D padded. Here's a forkable example https://www.kaggle.com/morenoh149/pad-sequences-soundfile